# psycopg2 connect error: cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, json, python

I am trying to pass json object as a parameter to my stored procedure. I tried many things and solved couple of error atlast I am stuck with the error :
**Error :
psycopg2 connect error: cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM insert_usr_details_in_all_tables('{','"','N','...**
i tried json.dumps, json.loads etc but unfortunately nothing is working for me if i am executing the postgresql from scripts with same input it works fine. below is my stored procedure..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.insert_usr_details_in_all_tables(
    jsonobject text)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    skill_s  Text[] := '{}';
    selectedSkill TEXT;
    edu TEXT;
    email TEXT;
    phone TEXT;
    usr_name TEXT;
    clg TEXT;
    lstEmployer TEXT;
    gendr TEXT;
    skill_row_count  INTEGER;
    usr_id INTEGER;
    skl_id INTEGER;
    intEmailExist INTEGER;
    expen DECIMAL;
BEGIN

    -- Getting name
    SELECT jsonobject->'Name' into usr_name;
    
    -- Getting education
    SELECT jsonobject->'Education' into edu;
    
    -- Getting phone number
    SELECT jsonobject->'phone_number' into phone;
    
    -- Getting experience
    SELECT (jsonobject->>'Exp')::DECIMAL INTO expen;
    
    --Getting college
    SELECT jsonobject->'College' into clg;
    
    
    -- Getting last employer
    SELECT jsonobject->'CurrentEmployer' into lstEmployer;
    
    --Getting gender
    SELECT jsonobject->'Gender' into gendr;
    
    -- Getting Email
    SELECT json_array_length(jsonobject->'Email') into intEmailExist;
    IF intEmailExist > 0 THEN 
        email:=array(SELECT json_array_elements_text(jsonobject->'Email'));
    END IF;
    
    -- Insert user details in 'Extractor_usr_details' table.
    INSERT INTO public."Extractor_usr_details"(name, phone_number, email, exp, education, college, "currentEmployer", gender)VALUES ( usr_name, phone, email, expen, edu, clg, lstEmployer, gendr) returning "id" into usr_id;
    
    skill_s := array(SELECT json_array_elements_text(jsonObject->'Skills'));
    FOREACH selectedSkill IN ARRAY skill_s LOOP
        INSERT INTO public."Extractor_skills" (skill) SELECT selectedSkill WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM public."Extractor_skills" WHERE skill = selectedSkill)RETURNING id into skl_id;
        INSERT INTO public."Extractor_usr_skills" (skill_id, user_id) SELECT skl_id, usr_id WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM public."Extractor_usr_skills" WHERE skill_id = skl_id AND user_id = usr_id);
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
$BODY$;
```

and here is my python code to call the procedure..

```
   try:
   usrdetails = {'Name': 'Prashant Chandel', 'Education': 'B. Tech', 'Exp': 3.6, 'phone_number': '', 'College': '', 'CurrentEmployer': ['Tata Tele Services'], 'Gender': '', 'Skills': ['Spring boot', 'springioc', 'Css']}
        abc = json.dumps(usrdetails)
        print(type(abc))
        ps_connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                         password="demo",
                                         host="127.0.0.1",
                                         port="5432",
                                         database="postgres")

        cursor = ps_connection.cursor() 
        cursor.execute("call insert_usr_details_in_all_tables(?)" [abc])


    except (Exception) as err:
        print("\npsycopg2 connect error:", err)
        conn = None
        cur = None
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115289/discussion-between-mohammed-zuhair-and-gerard-h-pille).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer pg8000, because it knows how to handle bind variables.

A little example.  Nothing gets inserted, no tables are used, just checking json and variable handling.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.insert_subscriber (
    jsonobject inout json
)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    skill_s  Text[] := '{}';
    edu TEXT;
    email TEXT[] := '{}';
    phone TEXT;
    usr_name TEXT;
    clg TEXT;
    lstEmployer TEXT;
    gendr TEXT;
    intEmailExist INTEGER;
    expen DECIMAL;
BEGIN
    SELECT jsonobject->'Name',
           jsonobject->'Education',
           jsonobject->'phone_number',
           (jsonobject->>'Exp')::DECIMAL ,
           jsonobject->'College' ,
           jsonobject->'CurrentEmployer' ,
           jsonobject->'Gender' ,
           json_array_length(jsonobject->'Email'),
           ARRAY(select json_array_elements_text(jsonobject->'Email')),
           ARRAY(select json_array_elements_text(jsonObject->'Skills'))
      into usr_name,
           edu,
           phone,
           expen,
           clg,
           lstEmployer,
           gendr,
           intEmailExist,
           email,
           skill_s;

    jsonobject := to_json(email);

END;
$BODY$
```

Which is used in a python script as follows:

```python
    #! /usr/bin/python3

    import pg8000
    import json

    con = pg8000.connect('ghp',password='yoEri')

    ps = con.prepare("call insert_subscriber(:v)")

    vv = {'Name': 'Prashant Chandel',
          'Education': 'B. Tech',
          'Exp': 3.6,
          'phone_number': '',
          'College': '',
          'CurrentEmployer': ['Tata Tele Services'],
          'Gender': '',
          'Email': ['ghp@goodl.uck','ghp@stradivari.us'],
          'Skills': ['Spring boot', 'springioc', 'Css']}

    vvv=json.dumps(vv);
    print(vvv)
    for row in ps.run(v=vvv):
      print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on pg8000. I've been looking for a replacement for psycopg2 for precisely that reason.

Comment: Hi Lennart, just curious, how did pg8000 work out for you?

Comment: Hi Gerard, the project where I used it more or less died at that time (not because of the driver:-), so I have not evaluated it that much

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Hope you found something else to keep you busy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `callproc` needs to be a [list of parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.callproc). Therefore, if you pass in

```python
abc=json.dumps(stringObject)
cursor.callproc('insert_usr_details_in_all_tables', abc)
```

It will split the string. Instead use:

```python
cursor.callproc('insert_usr_details_in_all_tables', [abc,])
```

Comment: abc = json.dumps(jsonObject)                       
cursor.callproc('insert_usr_details_in_all_tables', [abc,])                                            psycopg2 connect error: insert_usr_details_in_all_tables(unknown) is a procedure
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM insert_usr_details_in_all_tables('{"Name": "Pr...
HINT:  To call a procedure, use CALL.

Comment: @Mohammedzuhair: it is not stated explicitly in the docs, but it seems that `callproc`, despite the name, only works with functions. Therefore, you'll have to execute on the cursor with e.g. `execute('CALL ...', args)`.

Comment: I tried using cursor.execute("{call insert_usr_details_in_all_tables(?)}", [abc,]) // here i got error psycopg2 connect error: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: {call insert_usr_details_in_all_tables(?)} I removed the ',' in parameter brackets but still the same

Comment: @Mohammedzuhair: remove `{}` around, this is not SQL syntax and, the parameter must be denoted as `$1`, IIRC.

Comment: I removed the {} and i tried with cursor.execute("call insert_usr_details_in_all_tables(?)" [abc,]) and this cursor.execute("call insert_usr_details_in_all_tables(?)" [abc]) it gives me error like psycopg2 connect error: string indices must be integers    --- here is parameter i m passing {'Name': 'Prashant Chandel', 'Education': 'B. Tech', 'Exp': 3.6, 'phone_number': '', 'College': '', 'CurrentEmployer': [ 'Status calls'], 'Gender': '', 'Skills': ['Spring boot', 'springioc', 'Css', 'microservices', 'Ioc', 'typescript', 'Kafka']}

Comment: @Mohammedzuhair: that is why I mentioned: "parameter must be denoted as `$1`". You currently use `?`. Sorry, if this was not explicit enough.

Comment: '$1' didn't worked for me instead I used '%s' which worked for me. This is update code to call the procedure 'cursor.execute("CALL insert_usr_details_in_all_tables ( %s )", [abc,])'..you helped me a lot.. thanks for your support..